# For DataContext, GetChangeSet stops working after SubmitChanges

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext

In our project, we have multiple [System.Data.Linq.DataContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext?view=netframework-4.7.1) objects for the different Windows forms.

When databound controls on the form are changed (like the Name), we enable or disable the Save Button by checking the [GetChangeSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset?view=netframework-4.7.1) method.

```
private void ContentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var changes = GetChangeSet();
    int numChanges = changes.Deletes.Count + changes.Inserts.Count + changes.Updates.Count;
    btnSubmit.Enabled = (numChanges > 0);
}
```

When the Save Button is clicked, we call [SubmitChanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges?view=netframework-4.7.1) on the Linq **DataContext** followed by a call to a [ClearCache extension](http://blog.robustsoftware.co.uk/2008/11/clearing-cache-of-linq-to-sql.html) on the **DataContext**:

```
bool IFormPanelAccessor.CommitChanges<T>(T record)
{
    _dc.SubmitChanges();
    _dc.ClearCache();
}
```

**ClearCache** is defined in a static extensions class as follows:

```
public static void ClearCache(this DataContext dc)
{
    dc.GetType().InvokeMember("ClearCache", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, dc, null);
}
```

After saving, subsequent changes in the **DataContext** are no longer detected with **GetChangeSet**.

There is a *trigger* on the database that is called after an *Insert* or *Update*. Would this somehow break the **DataContext**'s ability to detect changes?

How do I get **GetChangeSet** to detect changes on databound controls after a call to **SubmitChanges**?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the call to `ClearCache()`? Re: the trigger, depends what it does :)

Comment: Are you changing your connection string when you are switching DataContext?  Are you going to different Server,Different Databases on same server, or just different tables in same database?

Comment: @ardila, removing `ClearCache()` does solve that particular issue, but then other parts of the form do not update to see the changes.

Comment: @jdweng, this project uses the same connection string throughout. The Data Context is loading a view (a join of multiple tables).

Comment: This sound similar to DGV updates when DataSource is a DataTable.  The DGV doesn't automatically get updated when the datasource changes (in this case the datatable).  The form repaint doesn't get called so the data doesn't get updated.  The trick is to set the DGV datasource to null and then back to the DataTable which forces the DGVl to get repainted.

Comment: `DataContext` is not meant to be used as a long-lived connection object, imo. Forcing a call to an internal method smells a bit, too. From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) _"In general, a `DataContext` instance is designed to last for one "unit of work" however your application defines that term. A `DataContext` is lightweight and is not expensive to create. A typical LINQ to SQL application creates `DataContext` instances at method scope or as a member of short-lived classes that represent a logical set of related database operations."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to [jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng)'s comment in the original question, I found a way to reload the data.

```
private void CommitChanges()
{
    // mCustomer is a record from the CustomerRecords Linq DataTable
    var rowId = mCustomer.RowId;
    _dc.SubmitChanges();
    _dc.ClearCache();
    // After ClearCache, it seems I need to physically pull the data again:
    mCustomer = _dc.CustomerRecords.FirstOrDefault(c => c.RowId == rowId);
    // Use the new record to update the controls on the form
    LoadData(mCustomer);
}
```

My guess is that **ClearCache** was causing the current record to lose its connection to the data.

Seems simple in hindsight, but I just never realized that.